# Enable System Protection (Restore) via .bat or .ps1 in Windows 11

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-11, restore

I'm trying to automate a script that runs to enable system restore upon startup (yes, every time my PC boots).
I found this PowerShell script that seems to work when entered directly into a PowerShell terminal window.

Enable-ComputerRestore -Drive "C:"

But I want to turn it into a script file to run by placing in the Startup folder.
I've tried entering this script into notepad, saving as "All Files" as a ".ps1" and then set that file extension to open with PowerShell as the default app. But it loads a red error that quickly vanishes as the terminal window closes.

I usually place .bat files in the startup to launch programs, and I understand this can be done to launch a .ps1 file, but right now the .ps1 doesn't even work when launched by PowerShell that I set as its default app.

Is there an easier way to automate Enabling system restore silently preferably through a .bat script?

Answer (score 0):

The error you see in the pop-up will be around your PowerShell execution policy.

You have a few options;

1. Wrap your Powershell code in a batch file to bypass it so

> PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Enable-ComputerRestore
> -Drive 'C:'"

2. Unblock the script with something like

> ```
> Unblock-File -Path pathhere\script.ps1
> ```

3. Change your execution policy to RemoteSigned or Unrestricted like so

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

For more info on PowerShell execution policy you can refer to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Thanks! But I'm confused, if the powershell code is bypassed by inserting within a batch file, why would I need to add another script to unblock it?

Answer (score 0):

The following command enables System Restore on the C:\ drive.

```
wmic.exe /namespace:\\root\default Path SystemRestore Call enable "C:\"
```

Alternatively, use the PowerShell.exe command-line suggested to you by @Kuypotta.

**Note:** In either case, you must create a scheduled task for one of the commands and configure it to run at login. It won't work from the Startup folder.

Comment: Thanks. Is your version a purely .bat-compatible script, without any needs to change permissions or other prerequisites other than task scheduler?

Comment: Of course. It can be run from a Batch file as an administrator. Without admin rights, it's impossible to enable or disable System Restore. Also, you may need to use the full path to wmic.exe (`C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe`) if WBEM is not in the Path.

Comment: I use Windows Pro 11 at Home, so I guess no WBEM.
Does that mean the full script looks like this?
`C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /namespace:\\root\default Path SystemRestore Call enable "C:\"`

Comment: Why not run the command instead of guessing something? It should work on Home as well as Pro. Yes, the command-line you posted is correct. WMIC component is installed by default. Unless you removed the WMIC FOD manually via Settings → Apps, WMIC.exe should be present in the computer.

Comment: I don't just run commands because I always get errors and then have to back track because I didn't know something that I should have. This is why I asked here, because I want to learn in advance, instead of unnecessary hindsight.

Comment: Thank you! It worked manually! Before I set as scheduled task, is there a way I can set it to always run as admin? Even though I@m logged in as admin, the bat file still only works if I right-click to run as admin.

Comment: When configuring the scheduled task, enable the tickbox for "Run with highest privileges" so that the task runs as admin. Hope that info helps.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed! The answers were relevant and helpful to what I needed!

Comment: I just discovered that WMIC is deprecated so I guess I'll need to use powershell version. But I can't @Kuypotta to help me understand all the steps to create the powershell script as I'm a n00b.