# How can I check the value of ReturnValue of a WMIC command?

Tags: rename, wmic

When running WMIC commands sometimes the ReturnValue is not zero, indicating an error, such as :

```
wmic.exe ComputerSystem where "Name='%computername%'" call Rename Name="%newname%"
```

or

```
%WPath% /Namespace:\\root\default PATH SystemRestore Call Enable "C:\"
```

I have tried respectively :

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==;" %R in (
wmic.exe ComputerSystem where "Name='%computername%'" call Rename Name="%newname%" ^| findstr /RC:"\<ReturnValue =\>"'
) do echo %R
```

and :

```
%WPath% /Namespace:\\root\default PATH SystemRestore Call Enable "C:\"|find "ReturnValue = 0" >nul && goto :next
```

But this doesn't seem to work...
Can somebody help to handle and solve these please ?

Comment: are you aware of `%ERRORLEVEL%`and `IF ERRORLEVEL`

Comment: @Yorik : I don't see the relationship between ReturnValue and ERRORLEVEL ? When the operation is successful with a ReturnValue =0, I have also echoed %ERRORLEVEL% which is 1 ? I also want to get the value of ReturnValue which may be 5, 85...

Answer (score 0):

> ***[Deprecated features for Windows clientArticle
>
> [09/01/2023]  ✅ Windows 10  ✅ Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features)***  
> ***Windows Management Instrumentation Command line (WMIC) tool.***
> *The WMIC tool is deprecated in Windows 10, version 21H1 and the 21H1 General Availability Channel release of Windows Server.
> This tool is superseded by Windows PowerShell for WMI.
>
> ***Note:*** This deprecation only applies to the **command-line management tool**.*
> ***WMI itself isn't affected. 21H1***

---

Use or invoke Powershell

```bash
set "_var=NEWMANECOMPUTER"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -C  "Rename-Computer -ComputerName "." -NewName $env:_var 2>$null ; $?" | find "True" >nul && echo/Done! || echo/nOp!
```

---

**Obs. 1:** You can test the command behavior without performing the action with `-WhatIf | -wi`:

```bash
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -C "Rename-Computer -ComputerName "." -NewName $env:_var 2>$null -wi ; $?" | find "True" >nul && echo/Done! || echo/nOp!
```

---

**Obs. 2:** To change the name you need Admin credentials to perform this action and also restart to be effective

```
Rename-Computer -ComputerName "." -NewName $env:_var -Restart
```

---

**Obs. 3:** Pay attention to the characters allowed to compose your **[`%NewComputerName%`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/which-characters-are-acceptable-for-a-computer/fddb4895-4295-47ab-a2b9-7773b329718c)** variable and meet the maximum length of 15 characters

---

The same applies to:

```bash
wmic /Namespace:\\root\default PATH SystemRestore Call Enable "C:\"
powershell -NoP -Ex -By -C "Enable-ComputerRestore -Drive 'C:'; $?" | find "True" >nul && echo/Done! || echo/nOp!"
```

---

- Additional Resources:

- [`Rename-Computer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-7.3) & [`Rename-Computer` (ss64.com)](https://ss64.com/ps/rename-computer.html)
- [`ErrorLevel` equivalent in PowerShell? `$?`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/errorlevel-equivalent/)
- [PowerShell How to suppress error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694632/powershell-how-to-suppress-error-messages)
- [Which characters are acceptable for a computer name?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/which-characters-are-acceptable-for-a-computer/fddb4895-4295-47ab-a2b9-7773b329718c)
- [Enable System Protection (Restore) via .bat or .ps1 in Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1772155/enable-system-protection-restore-via-bat-or-ps1-in-windows-11)